# What is the global warming potential (GWP) of any gas over a 1 day time frame?

Tags: climate-change, greenhouse-gases

Since in 100 years, the global warming potential (GWP) of methane is 28-36, what will be the GWP in 1 day time frame?
Can it be calculated that way?

Answer (score 1):

It can, but it's not very helpful. A large number of gasses (methane being one) decompose relatively quickly in the atmosphere to form other compounds. A longer time horizon means you capture all of that change in the metric (as compared to CO2), while if you did it for a day you'd end up with a figure that only really made sense for that day. The details of how it's calculated and why the time horizons are where they are is in the [IPCC AR5 WG1 CH8 technical supplement](https://www.ipcc.ch/site/assets/uploads/2018/07/WGI_AR5.Chap_.8_SM.pdf) (8.SM.11.1 Equations for the Global Warming Potential)

Comment: thanks for fixing the link @klanomath